# Are aliphatic amines SABRE amenable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

Hyperpolarization of molecules via the [SABRE-SHEATH technique](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.5b01799) is a fairly new idea. Does anybody know if hyperpolarizing aliphatic nitrogens is possible? The articles I've read mostly use N-heterocyclic compounds like pyridine or imidazole as substrates. If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

There have been a number of interesting papers just this year on this. Simon Duckett from York is leading the charge, and has recently demonstrated successful hyperpolarisation of a number of amines, including ammonia, as well as a number amides. Previously, a limiting factor in the success of the SABRE method has been the ability of the substrate to coordinate to the catalyst centre. Recent results show that this can be overcome using a relayed polarisation transfer method using a co-ligand.

For a couple of examples, check out:

- [*Chem. Sci.* **2018,** *9* (15), 3677–3684](https://doi.org/10.1039/C8SC00526E)
- [*Sci. Adv.* **2018,** *4* (1), eaao6250](https://doi.org/10.1126/sciadv.aao6250)
- anything else by Simon Duckett in recent years